# Método de newton - Raphson

Tags: python, python-requests

Ayuda tengo no sé que me sale mal estoy haciendo el método de newton y me dan una función con muchos valores flotantes y no me sale

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

Uso esas librerias

```
f = lambda x : (50+(3749/100)/(x**2)(x - (197)/1000))  # definimos la función
dfx = lambda x :  (50(x**3 - (3749/500)*x + (295421)/(1000000))/(x**3))

xi = -2.8

tolera = 0.000005
```

Y me da error aquí, como usa varios flotantes y python no regresa retorna esos valores decidí ponerlos en la raíz

```
error = 1

while error > tolera:
 Raiz = xi - (lambda xi : (50+(3749/100)/(xi**2)(xi - (197)/1000))/(lambda xi :  
 (50(xi**3 - (3749/500)*xi + (295421)/(1000000))/(xi**3)))
 error = np.abs(Raiz - xi)/(Raiz)
 xi = Raiz

print("La raiz es ", Raiz)
```

Me arroja error en esta parte

```
error = np.abs(Raiz - xi)/(Raiz)
```

Me dice que invalid syntax, me ayudarían muchísimo

Comment: Veo varios errores. (1) Falta un paréntesis de cierre correspondiente al primer lambda. (2) No se pueden dividir lambdas, ejemplo: `res = (lambda x:x*2)/(lambda y:y+3)`: *unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'function' and 'function'*, primero tienes que evaluar la expresión para luego hacer la división. (3) Usa el caracter \ si quieres continuar una expresión larga en otra línea; a excepción de las listas, tuplas, diccionarios, Python entiende el salto de línea como final de la instrucción.

Answer (score 2):

Aparte de que hay varios errores de sintaxis en la línea:

```
  Raiz = xi - (lambda ...)
```

no se entiende qué intentas hacer en esa línea. En el método de Newton-Raphson de lo que se trata es de mejorar la aproximación, restándole la función dividida entre su derivada. Por tanto lo que tendrías que hacer sería simplemente:

```
 Raiz = xi - f(xi)/dfx(xi)
```

Entiendo que intentaste hacer esto, te dio errores, y al no saber resolverlos decidiste cambiar `f` y `dfx` directamente por sus definiciones lambda en esa misma expresión. Al intentar hacer esto introdujiste nuevos errores además de volver la ecuación completamente ilegible.

De modo que vamos a investigar mejor por qué la expresión correcta (que es la que acabo de poner más arriba) daba errores. El problema no estaba en esa expresión, que es correcta, sino en la propia definición de las funciones `f` y `dfx`. Estas tenían  más errores de sintaxis.

La primera estaba así:

```
f = lambda x : (50+(3749/100)/(x**2)(x - (197)/1000))  # definimos la función
```

y aquí el problema es que olvidaste un operador entre `(x**2)` y `(x - ...)` Al poner simplemente un paréntesis al lado de otro, aunque para un matemático eso significaría "producto", no es así para Python, que entiende que se trata de una llamada, siendo `(x**2)` la "función" a llamar y `(x-...)` el parámetro. El error es que `(x**2)` no es un expresión de tipo función y no puede ser llamada.

En definitiva, faltaba un operador que supongo que sería el `*`, con lo que debe escribirse así:

```
f = lambda x: (50+(3749/100)/(x**2)*(x - (197)/1000))  # definimos la función
```

La segunda definición decía así:

```
dfx = lambda x :  (50(x**3 - (3749/500)*x + (295421)/(1000000))/(x**3))
```

y aquí pasa lo mismo, olvidaste poner un `*` detrás del primer `50`. Aunque `50(x**3 ...)` matemáticamente se lee como un producto, Python en cambio lo lee como una llamada a una función donde la función sería `50` y todo lo que va entre paréntesis sería el parámetro. La forma correcta sería entonces:

```
dfx = lambda x:  (50*(x**3 - (3749/500)*x + (295421)/(1000000))/(x**3))
```

Con estas dos modificaciones ya funcionará el método de Newton-Raphson:

```
xi = -2.8

tolera = 0.000005
error = 1

while error > tolera:
 Raiz = xi - f(xi)/dfx(xi)
 error = np.abs(Raiz - xi)/(Raiz)
 xi = Raiz
```

### Nota adicional

La ejecución del código anterior sale -26.449161812742616. Creo que el resultado es incorrecto. Esa no es una raiz de la función f(x) (que, tal como ha sido definida tendría por solución x≈-0.91180). El error estaría en que `dfx` no es una expresión correcta para la derivada de `f`. Pero este ya es un problema matemático y no de programación.

Revisa que la implementación de `f` corresponda exactamente con la fórmula matemática que tienes para f(x), y que has calculado bien su derivada f'(x), y que `dfx` es la implementación correcta de esa derivada.

Si tienes dudas sobre cómo convertir la forma matemática a una implementación python en forma de lambda puedes editar la pregunta para pegar una imagen de la fórmula matemática para f(x) y para la f'(x) que has calculado.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias ya me quedo el código, es difícil aprender por tu cuenta y en efecto la raíz aproximada es -0.9...